# Security issue on web application using Firebug

Tags: java, jsp

I have developed a web application in JSP. I have many JavaScript validation for text validation in the JSP page. During the testing, I enabled Firebug in Firefox and cleared a function that validates and submits to a servlet. The web application allows to submit garbage value of the textfield. How to overcome this? Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You can never trust the client. You must validate all input on the server side. For example, in the servlet.

Use client side validation only as a convenience for the user, in addition to the validation on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

You should always validate on the server and not rely on client side validation. Client side validation is only a nice to have feature that makes it easier to give immediate feedback to the user and save unneccessary roundtrips from the client to the server and back.

Answer (score 0):

You always need the validate the data in the client side AND in the server site... Only client-side validation is not secure. :)